# Python socket , why would the program blocked?

Tags: python, sockets

My program blocked, and the Client never went out of the loop, what's wrong?

```
'''Client, send hello,world'''

import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 6969))
s.send(b'hello, world')
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print(data)
    else:
        break #never gets here


'''Server, first receive, then send'''
import socket, threading

def tr(sock, addr):
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print(data)
        else:
            break #never gets here
    sock.send(b'get it') 
    # sock.close()

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('localhost', 6969))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    sock, addr = s.accept()
    t = threading.Thread(target=tr,args=(sock, addr))
    t.start()
```

Comment: you have 2 "#never gets here" comments. Which one is it? because if the first one (non threaded) doesn't exit, I don't see how the second one could start.

Comment: First, it went to the second #never gets here, then, it blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client hanging is the expected behaviour, as no one initiates a socket shutdown.  `socket.recv()` blocks until data is available. It does not return None if your socket is alive but there is no data to be read.

If your intention on the server side is to receive a message, then do something, return a response and finally close connection, this works:

```
def tr(sock, addr):
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print(data)
            sock.send(b'get it')
            sock.close()
            break
        else:
            break #never gets here
```

This will read the message, send a response and close the socket. Now your client works as expected.

If you want to establish a more durable connection with messages flowing back and forth between your server and client, then you need to trigger socket close at some point, and your client will exit then. If you do not do this, your client will assume there is more data to come and wait in `recv()` until it becomes available.

Comment: Thanks, it works! What if data from the Client is more than 1024, and you are not allowed to change sock.recv(1024)? So you have to print data several times but only the last time you should close sock. How can I?

Comment: Then you need to build a mechanism to collect the full message. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?  If you need to build a data transimission mechanism delivering messages, you need a way to recognise when all data has been received.  This can be done by transmitting a fixed length "data length" value first. Or you can use a separator character (line feed, zero) to tell the server this is the entirety of the message.

Comment: You should always assume you do not receive the full message from a socket, or if your protocol can contain several messages, there can be several. So collect everything to a buffer. If the terminator character is present, do what your server is supposed to do (and remember there may be another message or a part of it after the terminator character so whatever follows forms the basis of your next buffer). If no terminator character is present, read again and repeat until it is.

Comment: Goal is only, that client says something  to server and server says something to client. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You can never trust a socket to transmit a "message". If you want to use messages and not build this mechanism yourself, you could use ZMQ module. Its interface is almost identical to sockets but it would ensure you always receive a full message instead of several messages or a partial message before your receiving function returns.

Comment: OK. Now i can just use, if data =='exit' or if data.endswith('exit'), then sock.close() and break or something.

Comment: Yes. In theory, though, you should prepare for the occasion that your server has for example received only "exi" from the socket when it calls recv. If there does not appear to be something that makes sense, you need to read again and sum everything up before parsing. And if your delimiter char is \n and you have commands "show", "version" and "exit", you might have "version\nshow\nexit\n" when you read, and if you only use "endswith", you will have ignored two commands that should be processed first.

Comment: This is the typical socket programming "problem". How to ensure you have the full message, and how to ensure you process every byte you receive from the socket.  Not impossible nor complicated but somewhat tedious.